# Existing VF Page code is failing with CORS Error

Tags: amazon-aws

I am not a SF Dev. at best, I am a experienced Admin. I have inherited a SF Org from the previous Admin and outside developers. There is an existing SF App Exchange App, S3-Link Basic from Neilon. The OOTB features of the App are working fine.

The previous team developed a VF Page, Apex Classes, Controllers, etc. that allowed for an image file to be uploaded to Cloudinary.com. The image was then "transformed" into 2 additional images, a new image created and a watermark added, and a new image created that is thumbnail sized. Those 3 images were then moved to AWS S3 for external file storage. Custom fields on the S3-Link object stored the links to the 3 images on AWS S3. **All of this has been working fine until recently.** In the past week, the move to AWS S3 is not working.

If I upload a file using the OOTB S3-Link upload the file is stored on AWS S3

I can manually upload a file to AWS S3

If I execute the VF page, the image is uploaded to Cloudinary, the transformations are executed and the two additional images are created. I can log into Cloudinary and see them.

No images are moved to AWS S3

The Chrome console log has this error repeatedly

This code was working in 2 different SF Orgs until recently

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://s3bucketname.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/General%20Files/20190604_122628-2JG.jpg' from origin 'https://mySFDCorgname--c.visualforce.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

I would post the code for the VF Page but it exceeds the character limit.

Comment: Can you verify CSP setting in working org and non working org. You can check CSP in org by navigating Setup > search for CSP > check the allowlisted URLs and its settings. 

Also check the CORS setting in working org and non-working org.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by updating the CORS permissions on the AWS S3 side. Basically, I added a JSON file that explicitly listed my SFDC org as an allowed URL. My guess is that there was a change in the security policy by AWS